# Output of locationTo() method

Tags: google-maps

I need help about understanding the output of distanceTo method.
it gives me an output justa like this:  1.092244935852855
I want to know what is this number meter, km, miles or something else because i want to compare it to another value.
I want to show only the markers that are not far than 3 km so i want to do it < 3km.
thank you!

Comment: locationTo or distanceTo? If `distanceTo`, you refer to the maps API on android?

Comment: yes i refer to the API on android, the method is location1.distanceTo(location2);

Comment: public double LlogaritDistancen(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        
  double Distanca;
  
  Location Vendndodhja1 = new Location("");
   Vendndodhja1.setLatitude(lat1);
   Vendndodhja1.setLongitude(lon2);
  Location Vendndodhja2 = new Location("");
   Vendndodhja2.setLatitude(lat1);
   Vendndodhja2.setLongitude(lon2);
   
  return Distanca = Vendndodhja1.distanceTo(Vendndodhja2);
     }

Comment: and the output that this method returns me is that big number

Comment: Both latitude and longitude of `Vendndodhja1` and `Vendndodhja2` are the same. This is correct?

Comment: no Vendndodhja1 is the start and the Vendndodhja2 is th finish

Comment: i call the method just like this: Toast mesazhi = Toast.makeText(Meeaferta.this, Double.toString(LlogaritDistancen(41.3236939, 19.8059444, 41.318966, 19.817409)), 5000);
  mesazhi.show();

Comment: Yes, but in your code you are providing latitude and longitude same for both locations. Look: `Vendndodhja1.setLatitude(lat1); Vendndodhja1.setLongitude(lon2);` and `Vendndodhja2.setLatitude(lat1); Vendndodhja2.setLongitude(lon2);` .

Comment: Bruno eu gosto agradecer voce muito, porque a seu ajuda foi muito importante pra mi. Muito Obrigada

Comment: where can i accept it

Comment: Just mark my answer as accepted, by click in the second icon below "0". Look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Done. Thank you very much! Good night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In maps API in Android, `distanceTo` returns **`the approximate distance in meters`**.

See more at reference documentantion: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

**EDIT**: the error is in how you provide latitude and longitude to your locations. So, change `LlogaritDistancen` to something like this:

```
public double LlogaritDistancen(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) { 
    Location start = new Location(""); 
    start.setLatitude(lat1); 
    start.setLongitude(lon1);

    Location finish = new Location(""); 
    finish.setLatitude(lat2); 
    finish.setLongitude(lon2); 
    return start.distanceTo(finish); 
}
```

Comment: i have read the documention but i can not understand what is the unit of that output cause on the dokumention it doesnt give an example. If that number is in metter than the distance is too big which in fact inst more than 1.5 km

Comment: If possible, enter the code you are using for locations.